# How to scale an Area so it is a bigger outline?

Tags: java, scale, graphics2d, java-2d, area

I have an area shape that I am using with graphics2D.setClip(area) to draw a texture. I need to scale that area up to a bigger version, but when I do that it sometimes messes up. With my way of doing it, which is giving the area an AffineTransform and then scaling and translating it, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjKox.png) happens. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here's a runnable example.

```
public class Areas extends JPanel {

Area area;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Areas();
}

public Areas() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(this);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    area = new Area();

    //this works fine
    area.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(300-70, 300-70, 100, 100)));

    //when you add more, it messes up
    //area.add(new Area(new Ellipse2D.Double(400-70, 400-70, 100, 100)));
    //I want it to show up as an outline similar to the result of just having one ellipse added
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setColor(Color.black);
    g2.draw(area);

    Area area2 = new Area();
    area2.add(area);

    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

    double scale = 2;
    at.scale(scale, scale);

    double xDiff = area.getBounds().getCenterX()*scale - area.getBounds().getCenterX();
    double yDiff = area.getBounds().getCenterY()*scale - area.getBounds().getCenterY();

    at.translate(-xDiff/2, -yDiff/2);

    area2.transform(at);

    g2.setColor(Color.red);
    g2.draw(area2);

}
```

}

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Trying to mess around with shapes which have been scaled, when they have already been translated is a real pain in the code.  What I tend to is create a template shape, which is positioned at `0x0` to begin with, from there I apply the scaling and THEN the translation, as scaling the object will effect it's translation/origin point as well